# CakePHP Authentication - Username and Password in different tables

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have the following tables:

```
People
Users
Emails
```

The user's password is stored in the `Users` table and I want them to use their default email address which is stored in the `Emails` table to authenticate. The email is indicated as their default by a boolean column in the `Emails` table.

How do I use CakePHP's Authentication component in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `/app/Controller/Component/Auth/MyFormAuthenticate.php` file, and setup `Auth` to use `MyForm` instead of `Form` for authentication.

In this file include the [authenticate](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/FormAuthenticate.php) function and the [_findUser](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php#L69) function.

You then need to override the `_findUser` function to suit your needs.

Thanks to Ceeram on the CakePHP freenode channel for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoulnd't split the info in separate tables. Put everything in your Users table, and then make one-to-one relationships.

Anyway, if you want to do it this way you should override the login() method in the UsersController.

Here you have an example: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/SeanCallan/2007/04/17/simple-form-authentication-in-1-2-x-x

This is the method you need to override:

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentlogin

**EDIT:**

Make your auth data depends on Users only. I mean, put email, username (if you have one), and password there. After that, if you have, for example, People table to record other info (first name, addres, phone, etc), make an one-to-one relationship with that table. If you have your Customer table, and your customer can be users, make a one-to-one relationship.

I ran into this troubles some time ago, and was useful to solve it as Django do, and is with this one-to-one solution.

Comment: thanks. Can you clarify what you mean by 'Put everything in your Users table, and then make one-to-one relationships.'.

Comment: I edited the original post. Hope you get the idea, my english isn't very good.

Comment: I want People to have many email addresses, and also want Users to log in with their default email address. How does this change your solution?

Comment: You mean that a person can login with different emails and passwords? That's definitely a bad idea. Each user should have just one credential.

Comment: No, a user can only login with their default email, and their password.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973620/cakephp-auth-with-multiple-users-tables) should be enough evidence that you will not be able to use multiple models for your Auth component. It only supports a string, not an array. But if you keep reading, there might be a work around for you.