# CakePHP Auth Component -- Possible to have two separate logins?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a CakePHP 2.0 app that uses the AuthComponent with `User` model to successfully login to manage posts and other controllers and models. I'll call that the "super admin" part of the site.

However, I need to create an entirely separate part of the site for advertisers. I have created model `Advertiser` and controller `AdvertisersController`. I have also created table `advertisers`. I am able to successfully add an advertiser user, but when I attempt to login, it fails with the invalid username or password error.

I followed suggestions in the Cookbook for [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) and tried both of these options in the `beforeFilter` of my `AdvertisersController`:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array(
        'userModel' => 'Advertiser', 
        'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'),
            'Form',
            'Basic'
    ));


$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Advertiser'),
    'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Advertiser')
);
```

Any ideas? Is it not possible to use the AuthComponent with two different models/controllers?

**EDIT:** I updated my AdvertisersController to this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Advertiser'),
        'Form',
        'Basic'
    );
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout'); // Letting advertisers register themselves

}
```

Now the login is failing altogether -- no failed password error. I even tried a bogus username and password. Here is the login method in my controller:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'advertisers', 'action' => 'admin'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

I added an `else print_r($this->data); exit;` statement after the close of the first if and got an empty array. Couldn't even get to the login page.

Also, the output for the form is this -- POST is the method.

```
<form action="/advertisers/login?url=advertisers%2Flogin" id="AdvertiserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please enter your username and password</legend>
        <div class="input text required">
            <label for="AdvertiserUsername">Username</label>
            <input name="data[Advertiser][username]" maxlength="50" type="text" id="AdvertiserUsername"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input password required">
            <label for="AdvertiserPassword">Password</label>
            <input name="data[Advertiser][password]" type="password" id="AdvertiserPassword"/>
        </div>    
    </fieldset>
    <div class="submit">
        <input  type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973620/cakephp-auth-with-multiple-users-tables

Comment: Thank you for the referral. That scenario was a bit different, though -- many models, one Auth login. I have two separate logins -- intentionally that way.

Comment: I'd use a single table for all users, and put them in different groups. [ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html) is one way to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reposted this question with more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167367/cakephp-2-x-auth-with-two-separate-logins). Joshua was a big help getting admin prefixing sorted out for this scenario. If it seems like "too much" for your app -- see his comments here. It looks more complicated than it is, and it helps keep user controls much more defined.