# CakePHP 2 separate login tables

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

I have a Cake website and it needs to have two separate logins, each one will have their own login form and see different pages, it would be nice to have two different tables because there are no similarities between the two types of people.

Each login form will only be used by certain people and they will never login to the other form, and vice versa.

Also, the two login tables have a relationship between them, which requires 2 tables?

Is this possible?

Comment: That does look like what i need but for an older version of Cake, maybe @deizel will see this :)

Comment: Same sort of concept, except the `identify` was moved to the authenticate objects and is called `authenticate` (or specifically the `_findUser` method on `BaseAuthenticate`).

Comment: So just change `identify` to `authenticate`? http://codepad.viper-7.com/1BX9fE

Comment: Not quite. Posted an answer which hopefully will clear up the authentication system for you. When it authenticates, it tries each object. We made custom objects (duplicating FormAuthenticate's logic) that use different models/tables. If the first fails, Cake tries the second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, add a couple of empty custom authenticate objects. We'll reuse the same logic that FormAuthenticate uses (that is, uses POST data to check the database for a user), but simply change the model within the object settings (later).

**app/Controller/Component/Auth/ModelOneAuthenticate.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class ModelOneAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate {
}
```

**app/Controller/Component/Auth/ModelTwoAuthenticate.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class ModelTwoAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate {
}
```

Then tell your app to use these objects to authenticate, and tell it what model to use. You can also customize the fields here. In your AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'ModelOne' => array(
                'userModel' => 'ModelOne',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'my_custom_username_field',
                    'password' => 'some_password_field'
                )
            ),
            'ModelTwo' => array(
                'userModel' => 'ModelTwo'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The first authentication object would check the `model_ones` table for a username in `my_custom_username_field` and password in `some_password_field`, while the second one would check `model_twos` using the standard `username` and `password` fields.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have done all the code and no errors so far, but when i go to a restricted page, it tries to go to users/login when i have said to go to agents/login - ay ideas why? THis is what i have: http://codepad.org/zvBeJFEX

Comment: You'll need to set the loginRedirect property: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$loginRedirect

Comment: I have set that like: http://codepad.org/zvBeJFEX - Would I need to add it to the newly created auth classes instead somehow?

Comment: Ah my bad, you need to set the correct loginAction var. loginRedirect is where they go *after* they login. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$loginAction

Comment: How can I specify separate loginRedirect, logoutRedirect and loginAction for both types of users ?

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal The same way you assign the other properties. Remember they're simple wrappers to `FormAuthenticate` so all of its methods and properties apply as if you were using `FormAuthenticate`. The book has more information about that, too.

Comment: I specified those parameters in the `beforeFilter` function according the controllers. Works good!

Comment: Hi there.How can i use this within the same controller?

Comment: @Ricbermo they're part of the component layer, so just tell the auth component on that controller to use these classes to authenticate.

Comment: @jeremyharris could you take a look at this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693998/cakephp-2-3-login-to-different-table-with-custom-auth-components?noredirect=1#comment24026946_16693998

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal can you tell me how you did this using beforeFilter or simply where did you put the code and what code, pleas help me as I am new to cakephp and still learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to just set a different session key for each login type:

```
if ($loginTypeOne) {
  $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form'=> array(
      'userModel'=> 'TypeOne',
      )
    );
  AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.TypeOne';
} else {
  $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form'=> array(
      'userModel'=> 'TypeTwo',
      )
    );
  AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.TypeTwo';  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When they have to login there is a similarity: Both will require it to enter credentials, usually an username/email and password. So a users table and a foo_profiles table and a bar_profiles table depending on the user type should work also.

If you really want to go with two total different tables and the MVC stack for them, then simply use two different controllers FooUsers and BarUsers and inside of each create a customized login method.

Comment: Each of the 2 user types will only ever have to login to their one form, never the other one. each form requires a different user account.

Do you know of any resources to help with "creating a customized login method". Thanks.

Comment: Yes, check this tutorial out: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html In the login method simply do whatever your requirements are.

Comment: I cant see any help on having two login tables, would I just move the code it says to put in AppController to its seperate controller?

Comment: If you have one users table use the UsersController::login() action. The method can take an arg to make a difference between the user types  and render a different view by calling render('something') depending on the type. You can also simply use another method like UsersController::foo_login() and ::bar_login(). I don't know your real goal, it all depends on what you want to do and how big the differences are. You implied that you want to use 2 tables for each user type I never said anything about having a *login* table!

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Basically, i have a website that multiple estate agents can login to, the estate agents are able to create accounts for their customers wanting to buy a house etc. the details stored for each customer is nothing like the details that are stored for each estate agent, they also have access to different parts of the website. I want to do it the way you suggested as it is simpler than the answer below, but want to make sure its the right solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this previously by writing custom Authentication components that extend from BaseAuthenticate.  As long as they implement the authenticate() method then you'll be able to do whatever you want to each of the different types of user.

In your AppController you need to register the different components by doing something like

```
    public $components = array(
    "Session",
    "Auth" => array(
        'authenticate'      => array("UserType1", "UserType2"),
    )
);
```

Check out the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) for the rest of it.

Comment: Would you be able to share some of the code you used please? (for the custom authentication object)

Comment: I'd prefer not to TBH.  The essence of it though is that if you're happy with the authenticated user, you return an array that then gets stored in $auth->user.  If you're not happy then you return 'false' and Cake deals with that.  The link that I provided takes you to the relevant section of the authentication controller for you.

Comment: So inside the new authentication object I'd just have to say `(if login & password match table 1){ return $row1; }elseif (login and password match table 2){ return $row2; }else{ return false; }` ??

Comment: Not quite.  The best thing to do is to set up an authentication component per user type.  In each one you would have (if login & password match table 1) { return $row 1} else { return false} and then in the other component, (if login & password match table 2) { return $row 1} else { return false}.  The order in which you register them in the authenticate array (shown above) is the order that they get checked.  The second component is checked if and only if the first fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can have a look on this.
Define Model for both login member and then define table which you want to use for the user.
set variable in model.


class SearchedCategory extends AppModel {  
    var $name = 'SearchedCategory';  
    Var useTable = 'give your table name here.';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';


}
```