# cakephp2 Auth Component with 2 users tables

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp 2.0 application with 'users' and 'administrators' but they are organized into 2 different tables, how can I check these 2 tables to login using Auth Component using the same  form? I tried with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135066/cakephp-2-seperate-login-tables) but you have to do 2 different forms, one for each model, is there a way to force the authentication to look inside two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some tries I sort this out, first I defined 2 authenticate , one for users and one for administrators,like this:

```
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class AdministratorAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate {
}
```

and

```
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class UserAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate {
}
```

now we can define the components variable in AppController like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
        'authenticate' => array(
                'Administrator' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                    'userModel' => 'Administrator'
                ),
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                    'userModel' => 'User'
                )
                )
    )
);
```

then in the login method of access controller I try the administrator login and then the users login in this way:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'administrator','action'=>'index'));
} 
else {
$this->request->data['Users']=$this->request->data['Administrator'];
unset($this->request->data['Administrator']);
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'user','action'=>'index'));
}
    else                            
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
```

The key here is modify the request->data array substituting the userModel 'Administrator' with 'User'